# Atmel microcontroller: difference between UBRR0H and UBRRnH

Tags: c, assembly, arduino, microcontroller, atmel

So I am reading up on programming an Atmel 328p and I want to be able to program serial input and output but I saw something I didn't completely get:

- UBRR0H is called UBRRnH in this assembly code:

  ```
  USART_Init:
      ; Set baud rate
      out UBRRnH, r17
      out UBRRnL, r16
      ; Enable receiver and transmitter
      ldi r16, (1<<RXENn)|(1<<TXENn)
      out UCSRnB,r16
      ; Set frame format: 8data, 2stop bit
      ldi r16, (1<<USBSn)|(3<<UCSZn0)
      out UCSRnC,r16
      ret
  ```
- While it stays as the name UBRR0H in this C code:

  ```
  #define FOSC 1843200 // Clock Speed
  #define BAUD 9600
  #define MYUBRR FOSC/16/BAUD-1
  void main( void ) {
      ...
      USART_Init(MYUBRR)
      ...
  }

  void USART_Init( unsigned int ubrr) {
      /*Set baud rate */
      UBRR0H = (unsigned char)(ubrr>>8);
      UBRR0L = (unsigned char)ubrr;
      Enable receiver and transmitter */
      UCSR0B = (1<<RXEN0)|(1<<TXEN0);
      /* Set frame format: 8data, 2stop bit */
      UCSR0C = (1<<USBS0)|(3<<UCSZ00);
  }
  ```

This code does the completely same according to Atmel who makes the CPU, so why can it be called two different things?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Atmel documentation](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8161.pdf) UBRRnL and UBRRnH are USART Baud Rate Registers.

The UBRRnH contains the four most significant bits, and the UBRRnL contains the eight least significant bits of the USART baud rate.

[image: USART Baud Rate Registers]

As I see if your device has multiple USARTs for example USART0 and USART1 you can choose the one you need by modifying `UBRRnL` and `UBRRnH` (and maybe other registers too). Change the `n` (in UBRRnL and UBRRnH) to the required USART id number and assign it to `UBRRnL` and `UBRRnH`.

For example in Assembly:

```
.equ USART = 1 
.if USART == 0 
    .equ UBRRnH = UBRR0H 
    .equ UBRRnL = UBRR0L 
 .else 
    .equ UBRRnH = UBRR1H 
    .equ UBRRnL = UBRR1L 
 .endif
```

So when Assembly code is generated from the C source, the compiler might compile the `UBRR0H`s and `UBRR0L`s to `UBRRnL` and `UBRRnL` and define them as `UBRR0H` and `UBRR0L`, as [Robert Harvey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18007104/1494454) stated.

Answer (score 3):

In [Nut/OS](http://www.ethernut.de/api/group__xg_usart_avr.html), I see this `#define`:

```
#define     UBRRnH   UBRR0H
```

It's entirely possible that they are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

In the datasheet (using the The ATmega164P/324P/644P datasheet), Atmel explains the use of 'n' in the naming. It is because the MCU has 2 USARTs, USART0 and USART1 so it is upon you to replace 'n' with '0' or '1' depending on the USART you are using.
Use of `#define` can solve this,

```
#define UBRRnH UBRR0H
```